# Is there a way to tell the compiler that a specific block of code will always be executed?

Tags: c#

We have the following construct in our codebase, used to ensure a particular resource is disposed of after use:

```
using (var disposableThing = DisposableThing.Begin())
{
    // do something

    disposableThing.Finish(); // must always be called
}
```

Here's an example of its usage:

```
List<int> ids;

using (var disposableThing = DisposableThing.Begin())
{
    ids = disposableThing.GetSomeIds();

    disposableThing.Finish();
}

DoSomethingElseWith(ids);
```

Since this pattern is so common, we wrote a method on `DisposableThing` to encapsulate it:

```
static void ExecuteWithFinish(Action<DisposableThing> action)
{
    using (var disposableThing = Begin())
    {
        action(disposableThing);

        disposableThing.Finish();
    }
}
```

which allows us to rewrite the second sample as:

```
// #4
List<int> ids;

DisposableThing.ExecuteWithFinish(disposableThing =>
{
    ids = disposableThing.GetSomeIds();
});

DoSomethingElseWith(ids); // compiler error "Use of unassigned local variable 'ids'"
```

But the compiler refuses to compile that code because it has no way to know that `ids` will always be assigned after `ExecuteWithFinish` has completed (or thrown an exception, which will prevent the execution of `DoSomethingElseWith` anyway).

- I know I could add an overload of `ExecuteWithFinish` that returns values from a passed-in `Func`, which is ugly.
- I know I could subclass `DisposableThing` and override its `Dispose` method to call `Finish`, which is a cleaner, neater, and faster way than constructing a delegate each time (this is probably what I'll end up doing).

But for my own edification and in the spirit of "what if", is it possible to inform or even trick the compiler into allowing the code in #4 as written?

**edit:** Yes, I know I could write `List<int> ids = null;` and circumvent this issue entirely, but (a) I'd prefer not to perform unnecessary assignments (b) I'd like to change the code as little as possible.

Comment: I note that the comment for `disposableThing.Finish()` says "must always be called". Does that hold true even if the `do something` throws an exception? Because if so, you should encapsulate the entire `Begin()` `Finish()` `Dispose()` thing in a separate class that you can manage with a single `using`.

Comment: Just a general remark: Why not use the `IDisposable` pattern, which seems way more obvious than reinventing the mechanism using a `Finish` method? Put the code from `Finish` into your `Dispose` method (or simply call `Finish` from `Dispose`). That way you avoid the compiler error and get support from the language because the code in `Finish` will automatically called at the end of the using statement.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: From the documentation there I'd have assumed `Finish` to be called in `Dispose` anyway. I mean, there's hardly a better use case for `IDisposable`. After all, streams are also automatically closed when disposed and you don't have to call `Close` manually in that case ...

Comment: @Joey You would hope so - but in that case, why is the OP's code calling it explicitly?

Comment: Guys, I already noted that I know I can (and probably should) use `IDisposable` correctly for this. **That's not my question.** My question is **can I do this potentially useless thing and if so, how**.

Comment: Assigning `null` is not an unnecessary assignment; it doesn't even create an instance on the heap, so it's basically free.

Comment: @Ian, in that case, assigning `null` _is_ effectively the hint to the compiler that the list is always assigned.

Comment: Note that it isn't possible to produce verified, managed code with uninitialized locals, so the compiler's hands are tied here -- it *can't* take your word for it. On the IL level, locals *must* be definitely assigned before use and the runtime does not perform code flow analysis for obvious reasons of efficiency and complexity (and the possibility of proxies, dynamic code, and...) The restriction could technically be waived for unverified code, but you can see why that wasn't a high priority.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a different approach here.

I'm going to make the assumption that for some reason you must have a `Finish()` method that must always be called before `Dispose()`, which must also always be called.

That may be a rash assumption, and it does rather beg the question: Why don't you put the functionality of `Finish()` into the `Dispose()`? However...

Firstly, create an interface to encapsulate a disposable thing with a `Finish()` method:

```
public interface IDisposableThingWithFinish : IDisposable
{
    void Finish();
}
```

and change your `DisposableThing` class so that it implements `IDisposableThingWithFinish`.

Then you could write a disposable class that encapsulates calling `Finish()` and then `Dispose()` like so:

```
public sealed class DisposingFinisher : IDisposable
{
    readonly IDisposableThingWithFinish _item;

    public Disposing(IDisposableThingWithFinish item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

        _item = item;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            _item.Finish();
        }

        finally
        {
            _item.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You would use `Finisher` like so:

```
using (var disposableThing = new DisposingFinisher(DisposableThing.Begin()))
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple null-assignment will avoid the compiler warning as explained in the documentation of [compiler error CS0165](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx):

```
List<int> ids = null;
```

Comment: Completely correct, but I'd like to get away without the unnecessary assignment, as per my edit.